# retirar item de exibição php

Tags: php, for

Tenho um problema aqui, sei que pode ser coisa simples, porém ainda não consegui resolver sozinho.

Tenho um *slide* rodando em um *loop* de PHP, neste slide existem "entidades" que quando chegar o dia de expiração eles devem ser retirados do *slides*, apenas dos *slides*, ou seja, apenas não seriam mais exibidos.

Já tentei o `unset()` porém ele retira todos os produtos, pois todos tem que vir de uma mesma *query*.

Comment: Coloca o código que você ja tem.

Comment: $fim_destaque = $produto->data_expiracao;
                                    
                                    if( $fim_destaque == date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ){                               
                                       unset($produto->data_expiracao);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como não dás muito detalhe na tua questão tentarei adivinhar.

Num slide tens produtos que só podem estar nesse slide até ao dia dd/mm/yyyy, certo?

Faz essa seleção logo no mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE data_ativa > CURDATE();
```

Assim seleccionas apenas os produtos que estão ativos até HOJE - curdate() - Amanha já não estarão no slide.

Se a minha resposta não ajudar em nada, por favor detalha melhor a tua dúvida.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rui Costa, é isto mesmo que você disse, vou tentar sua solução e posto aqui se deu certo.

Comment: Rui Costa deu certinho, muito obrigado, sua ajuda foi de mais, muito obrigado.